# In which cases does encode/decode utf8 croak?

Tags: perl, encoding, decoding

This script gives me two times the same output. Are there encoding which would not survive the `utf8` `encode` and `decode` between the two `say`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.16.1;
use Encode qw/encode decode/;

my $my_encoding = 'ISO-8859-7';
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding($my_encoding)";

my $var = "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU}";
$var .= "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA WITH TONOS}";
$var .= "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER UPSILON WITH DIALYTIKA}";

$var = encode( 'utf8', $var );
$var = decode( $my_encoding, $var );

say $var;

my $test = encode( 'utf8', $var, Encode::FB_CROAK );
$var = decode( 'utf8', $test, Encode::FB_CROAK  );

say $var;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It croaks if you try to encode something that falls outside of the target encoding's character set.

`utf8` is a Perl-specific encoding used by Perl to store 72-bit characters. It is similar to UTF-8, but it is different. It supports every character Perl supports, so it will never croak.

On the other hand, if you were to use `UTF-8`, it would will croak if you try to encode something that isn't a Unicode character (e.g. `chr(0x200000)`).

See also: [`:encoding(UTF-8)` vs `:encoding(utf8)` vs `:utf8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040165/589924)

Comment: If I would have written `utf-8`, how would be the answer concerning the different encoding?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: encode-decode with the same encoding should always work if the encode works. It might be possible that you won't get exactly what you started with, but I don't know when you wouldn't.

Comment: I hope I have understood: I start with characters (decoded) and the character which can be encoded by the different encoding are a subset of the Unicode characters. So only binary data could croak this.

Comment: In the case of utf8, the character set is a proper *superset* of Unicode.

Comment: Re, "So only binary data could croak this.", what's "this"?

Comment: "binary data" doesn't have a definition, but that won't croak for any sequence of bytes. They would be treated as U+0000..U+00FF (since bytes 00..FF == chars 00..FF), all of which exist.

Comment: What did you use. What input did you give, specifically? What error did you get? Come on, you know better that that.

Comment: I used DBI/DBD::SQLite with `sqlite_unicode` enabled. No with `sqlite_unicode` disabled it works. The error was "Malformed UTF-8 character ...".

Comment: that's not encode croaking. That's from Perl itself because SQLite created a corrupt scalar (as a result of you asking it)