# Extra empty elements when using XML::LibXML::Reader instead of XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl

I'm looking to parse a Wordpress blog export - I've used some XML::LibXML code successfully on my sample output of 3 blog entries, however I decided to try using XML:LibXML:Reader since I'm expecting to have to parse a very large file and I am concerned about running out of memory.

However, I'm getting some extra blank nodes.

The problem can be demonstrated using the following code and XML document:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => $filename) or die;

my $entry_pattern = 'XML::LibXML::Pattern'->new('/rss/channel/item');

while ($reader->nextPatternMatch($entry_pattern)) {
    say "MATCH";
    my $item = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    say $item;
    say 'Title: ', $item->findvalue('./title');
    say "";
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>Blog</title>
      <item><title>Title 1</title></item>
      <item><title>Title 2</title></item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

The output obtained:

```
MATCH
<item><title>Title 1</title></item>
Title: Title 1

MATCH
<item/>
Title:

MATCH
<item><title>Title 2</title></item>
Title: Title 2

MATCH
<item/>
Title:
```

Note the extra `<item/>` matches. Where do these come from? How can I avoid them?

Comment: Re "*I've cleansed all the wide characters out of the input file and re-run....*", eh... Better to encode your outputs!!! `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`

Comment: [`:utf8` is wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040165/589924) You want `:encoding(UTF-8)` as I showed. The directive I showed does this, and does it for STDIN and STDERR as well (which you need for error messages), and sets the default encoding for any `open` used in scope (which you don't have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the end tag is being matched. A pull/stream parser like ::Reader needs to signal both the start and end of elements, so this makes sense. Imagine if we `->copyCurrentNode` wasn't used.

However, we do use `->copyCurrentNode`, so we don't care about them or want them. So we'll simply have to skip them using the following:

```perl
next if $reader->nodeType != XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT;
```

or

```perl
next if $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT;
```

Demo:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader qw( XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT);

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => $filename );

my $entry_pattern = 'XML::LibXML::Pattern'->new( '/rss/channel/item' );

while ( $reader->nextPatternMatch($entry_pattern) ) {
    next if $reader->nodeType != XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT;

    say "MATCH";
    my $item = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    say $item;
    say 'Title: ', $item->findvalue( './title' );
    say "";
}
```

```
MATCH
<item><title>Title 1</title></item>
Title: Title 1

MATCH
<item><title>Title 2</title></item>
Title: Title 2
```